# How to use svg files with i tag in React JS

Tags: reactjs, svg, icons

In React JS , I have an svg file in a folder, I am trying to use it in another jsx file inside an i tag. Is it possible to use it like this?

```
import React from "react";
import activityIcon from '../relativePath/icons/activity.svg

const NavMenu = () => {
    return (
           <div>
                <i src={activityIcon} /> <span>ListName</span>
           </div>
           )
    }

export default NavMenu
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use the SVG file like that.

Instead, you need to import the SVG file as a React component and then use it in your JSX code as a component. Here's how you can do it:

```
import { ReactComponent as ActivityIcon } from '../relativePath/icons/activity.svg';
```

And then add the imported component in your JSX like this:

```
const NavMenu = () => {
    return (
        <div>
          <i><ActivityIcon /></i> <span>ListName</span>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
export default NavMenu;
```

I hope this will work for you